# how to convert array to key value pair in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, react-final-form

I am using `react-final-form` with `semantic-ui` in my demo .I use multiple select dropdowns in my demo .

I convert `multiselect` dropdown to `single select` (I like the design having chip like structure) .

but my form data response incoming like this when I select any value.
**form response when user select any value**

```
{
  "dropdown": [
    "ax"
  ]
}
```

**expected response**

```
{
      "dropdown": "ax"

    }
```

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cerf-kg41n

I convert `mutiselect` to single select like this

```
onChange={(e, data) => {
          if (data.value && data.value.length > 1) {
            data.value.shift();
          }
          return input.onChange(data.value);
        }}
```

Comment: How would you want the data for multiple items? Can you update your expected response to contain multiple items?

Comment: i don't want multiple items ..but i need chips.chip mean "gray backgound" with cross buttom

Comment: in my demo user only select one item at one time

Comment: but it design look like multiple select

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it fits your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mutate the values on submit to fit your needs like this:

```
 const onSubmit = async values => {
  await sleep(300);
   const transformedValue = {
       dropdown: values.dropdown[0]
   } 
   window.alert(JSON.stringify(transformedValue , 0, 2));
 };
```

This will result in the desired outcome and keeps the chip view.

Comment: but my chip gone...:(

Comment: i need that chip "grey background with cross button"

Comment: please remove your answer ..!!

Comment: Relax, i updated my answer so that you can keep that chip layout.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cerf-kg41n see my code I am not using renderSelect

Comment: Try this(updated answer), this will result in the correct data being send on submit.

Comment: hmmm..i already use this .but it fail in the second time.steps please select any item then press button and again press button (2 times) see result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197389/discussion-between-domino987-and-user944513).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, instead of returning this,

```
return input.onChange(data.value);
```

return this,

```
return input.onChange(data.value[0]);
```

Comment: That will remove the chip view. And he needs the chip.

Comment: it remove chip ..:(